# Python style with-statement in C

Tags: c

I thought about using a macro to auto close `FILE` pointers at the end of a block. My solution so far is:

```
FILE *fopen_safe(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, mode);

    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}

#define with_fopen(fp, filename, mode) \
    for (FILE *fp = fopen_safe(filename, mode), _invariant = { ._r = 1 }; _invariant._r--; fclose(fp))


// Usage:
with_fopen(fp, "test", "w") {
    fprintf(fp, "test\n");
}
```

This solution is not elegant as i am using an int in the struct to create my loop invariant.

Is there another way to auto close files? Can a block be associated with a macro in a smarter way?

Comment: *Is there another way to auto close files?* Port your code to C++ :-)  C really can't do this in any reasonable way.  Just a fact of life.

Comment: Use function pointers along with a `void *` to fake closures. Not nice, but works unless you're using longjmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few problems with this macro.

- It relies on an undocumented layout of `FILE` structure
- It cannot be nested (try it with `-Wshadow`)
- It assumes that the block is *always* left through the end
- It may create suprises:

  ```
      for (....) {
          with_fopen(fp, ...) {
              int rc = do_something(fp);
              if (rc == -1) {
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  The programmer (with or without Python background) expects the outer loop to be broken. Instead the loop hidden inside `with` is.

Nice try however.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, C just isn't designed for this kind of thing.  Or more accurately, C can do this perfectly fine, but not within what is commonly called "structured programming."

In C++, the correct answer would be RAII.  In Java, it would be try-with-resources.  In C, we have none of those things.  Instead, the least bad way to do cleanup code in C is with `goto`:

```
int func(/* arguments */) {
    int rc = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(/*...*/);
    if(!fp){
        rc=errno;
        goto err_fp;
    }
    buf = malloc(/*...*/);
    if(!buf){
        rc=errno;
        goto err_buf;
    }
    /* Put some code here
     * In this block, don't write return retval;
     * Instead, write rc=retval; goto out;
     */
out:
    free(buf);
err_buf:
    fclose(fp);
    /* fclose() error checking elided for simplicity.
     * You have to call it in a loop to handle EINTR correctly.
     */
err_fp:
    return rc;
}
```

This ensures that buf is only freed if it was successfully malloc'd,* fp is only closed if it was opened, and all resources are cleaned up on every code path.

* `free(NULL)` is [legal and harmless](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free).  In real code, you should take advantage of this (e.g. by merging the `err_buf` label into the `out` label).  I'm only using malloc/free as an example to show how this pattern nests.